# Transform recursion for coefficients into differential equation for generating function

Tags: differential-equations, polynomials, recursion

Assume, one is given a linear recursion with polynomial coefficients for a sequence $(a_i)_i$, such as

```
a[i] == i a[i-1]
```

I would like to convert this recursion into a differential equation for the (formal) generating function $G(x)=\sum_{i}a_i x^i$.

In my example above, direct manipulation leads me to the equation
$$
G(x)=2x^2 a_1+x^2 G'(x)+xG(x)
$$
which Mathematica can solve in terms of special functions. Interestingly, the power series with coefficients $i!$ (the solution to $a_i=i a_{i-1}$) doesn't converge for any $x$. Since I'm only interested in formal power series, however, I still believe that my question makes sense.

I'm particular interested in a method that also works for higher order recursions with higher degree polynomial coefficients.

Thanks.

I would like to add that I am familiar with the functions GeneratingFunction[] and RSolve[] but neither seems to be of much help for this problem.

**Edit 18 April 2014:**
In version 9 the behaviour of `GeneratingFunction` appears to have [changed in such a way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45967/derivative-of-generating-function-example-from-documentation) that it doesn't directly solve this problem any longer. I therefore reactivate this question and ask for a way to transform a linear recursion with polynomial coefficients into a differential equation for the generating function.

Comment: GeneratingFunction[] does what I want. Apparently I wasn't sufficiently familiar with this function after all.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach for problems like these is to combine `GeneratingFunction[]` (as already noted by the OP) with `DifferenceRoot[]`, as in the following:

```
GeneratingFunction[DifferenceRoot[Function[{a, k}, {a[k] == a[k - 1]/k, a[0] == 1}]][k],
                   k, x]
   DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {-y[x] + y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}]][x]
```

after which one can use `FunctionExpand[]`:

```
FunctionExpand[%]
   E^x
```

**However**, for the OP's specific case involving the exponential integral, `GeneratingFunction[]` refuses to budge at all, even after setting `VerifyConvergence -> False`. One possible recourse is to directly construct the regularized sum:

```
Sum[DifferenceRoot[Function[{a, k}, {a[k] == k a[k - 1], a[0] == 1}]][k] x^k,
    {k, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
   -((E^(-1/x) Gamma[0, -(1/x)])/x)
```

and then you can use `DifferentialRootReduce[]` to see the associated ODE:

```
DifferentialRootReduce[%, x]
   DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {y[x] + (-1 + 3 x) y'[x] + x^2 y''[x] == 0,
                                      y[1] == -(Gamma[0, -1]/E), y'[1] == 1}]][x]
```

Note that the initial conditions were not placed at $x=0$ even if the function is actually well-defined there.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of "formal power series" of this type.  I have an example of a very competent mathematics professional that led him into ?? land.
Concerning your question let's look at the condition
$a_0=0\cdot a_{-1} $ which is off the end but doesn't matter because it sets $a_0 = 0$

But by recursion this sets all

$a_x = 0 $

So the relation can  only be non-trivially true for i>0.
BTW: direct calculation doesn't seem to need $2x^2a_1$
In other words.

$G(x)-x^2 G'(x)-xG(x)$  seems to be zero.
Gathering the $x^i$ terms
$a_i x^i - x^2 x^{i-2} a_{i-1}(i-1) - x^1 x^{i-1} a_{i-1} = a_i x^i - i a_{i-1}x^i $

Which is the requirement.  Adding another term makes in non-homogenious.  In addition evaluating the left and right hand sides for $x^2$ gives

$a_2 x^2 = 2a_1 x^2 +a_1 x^2 + a_1 x^2$ 
$a_2 = 4 a_1 $  together with $a_2=2a_1 $ 
Doesn't work!  Unless you start the recursion at i>2.

Sorry for being a little "long winded"