# Derivative of generating function (Example from documentation)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, documentation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

In the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeneratingFunction.html) for `GeneratingFunction`, the following example is given under Examples -> Properties & Relations -> Derivative:

```
GeneratingFunction[n f[n], n, z]
(*z (GeneratingFunction^(0,0,1))[f[n],n,z]*)
```

When I evaluate the input, however, I obtain something different, namely:

```
GeneratingFunction[n f[n], n, z]
(*z GeneratingFunction[(1 + n) f[1 + n], n, z]*)
```

For me the first output would be preferable; indeed I would like Mathematica to express any expression of the form

```
GeneratingFunction[p[n] f[n], n, z] (*p[n] an explicit polynomial in n*)
```

in terms of derivatives of the generating function of the sequence `f[n]`. I think this is the intended behaviour of `GeneratingFunction` and certainly what I remember from v8.

**Question:**
Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

I am currently using version 9.0 on a 64bit Linux computer.

Comment: Same in 9.0.1 Windows. `ZTransform` behavior similarly changed it appears.

Comment: The issue persists in the Raspberry Edition of Mma v10.

Comment: This is a bug either of the function or of the documentation.  I have tagged it accordingly.  Whether the change in behavior was intentional or not I cannot say.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to have been resolved

[image: screenshot]